# One To One relationship in Django

Tags: django, oop, inheritance, model, one-to-one

I need to make a profile for each user with address and city, and more... with OneToOne relationship in Django models, So I don't know how I can do it, I want to inheritance class Profile from Class User.

and I'v got this error :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (address) specified for User
```

this is my model:
#models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, fav_color, lastname, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False,):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        # if not phone_number:
        #     raise ValueError('user must have phone number')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            fav_color=fav_color,
            lastname=lastname,
            city=profile.city,
            address=profile.address,

        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, fav_color, lastname,):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            fav_color=fav_color,
            lastname=lastname,
            

        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fav_color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # Email & Password are required by default.
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fav_color', 'lastname',]

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permission to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user an admin member?"
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active


class profile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120),
```

actually i don't know how can i use OneToOne models , and how can i inheritance  from base class to order  classes
please help , tank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Django model like that. `User(AbstractBaseUser)` is right because `AbstractBaseUser` is abstract. There're 2 options

1. Not recommended, add more fields (city, address...) to User.
2. Define `class Profile(models.Model)` as you did, create a profile once User was created.

#### How?

Assuming you have an `accounts` app that contains `Profile` model.

file accounts/models.py, define profile field as you did

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

file `accounts/__init__.py`, define app configuration will be used.

```
default_app_config = "accounts.apps.Config"
```

file accounts/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

file accounts/signals.py, install signals

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver, Signal
from accounts.models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_related_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    Once a new User instance was saved:
    Check User instance, if this is new instance (created is True)
    then create a Profile for this user.
    """
    if not created:
        return
    default_data = dict(city='', address='')
    instance.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance, **default_data)
```

Don't forget to add `accounts` to your INSTALLED_APPS config.

Comment: actually I don't understand! , about signals , __init__.py ..

Comment: `__init__.py` is used to define what configuration of app will be used.

`signals.py` is used to received notification when some where in app notify an event. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/ .


In this case, we use `post_save` for sender User. That means once User.save() was called, a post_save signal will be dispatch, we listen on this one to create related Profile.